# Cannot import biluo_tags_from_offsets from spacy.gold

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am trying to import biluo_tags_from_offsets from spacy.gold but cannot do it.
Getting ModuleNotFoundError.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-d17a54331c7a> in <module>
      3 
      4 import spacy
----> 5 from spacy.gold import biluo_tags_from_offsets
      6 nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_lg")
      7 

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy.gold'
```

How can I use this spacy.gold module. I have already installed spacy.
I am an amateur, sorry if this question does not make any sense.
Any kind of help is appreciated.
Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://spacy.io/api/top-level) says, `spacy.gold` was disabled in spaCy 3.0. If you have the latest spaCy version, that is why you are getting this error.

You need to replace `from spacy.gold import biluo_tags_from_offsets` with `from spacy.training import offsets_to_biluo_tags`.